Assembly error when compiling C code with ASM instructions
I'm new to assembly language programming and I'm having a problem with a C program that incorporates assembly instructions (ASM) to reverse a string. The code works without errors on my Debian virtual machine (running on VirtualBox), with Windows 11 as the host OS. However, some of my colleagues are getting assembly errors when compiling it on their virtual machines. When I compile it using gcc -Wall -g program.c -o program on my machine, I don't find any errors, but they do:
program.c: Assembler messages:
program.c:26: Error: (%rdx,%ecx)' is not a valid base/index expression
program.c:27: Error: (%rdx,%esi)' is not a valid base/index expression
program.c:28: Error: (%rdx,%ecx)' is not a valid base/index expression
program.c:29: Error: (%rdx,%esi)' is not a valid base/index expression

The C code I am using is as follows:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[10000]; // Allow for 10000 characters

    // Prompt user for input
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

    // Remove newline character if present
    char *nl = strchr(str, '\n');
    if (nl != NULL) {
        *nl = '\0';
    } else {
        printf("Line too long or no newline character found.\n");
    }

    // Validate string length
    int length = strlen(str);
    if (length > 50) {
        printf("String exceeds 50 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Inline assembly to reverse the string
    __asm__ (
        "mov %[len], %%esi\n\t"    // esi = length
        "decl %%esi\n\t"            // esi = length - 1 (last character index)
        "xor %%ecx, %%ecx\n\t"      // ecx = 0 (starting index)
        "reverse_loop:\n\t"
        "cmp %%esi, %%ecx\n\t"      // Compare start and end indexes
        "jge loop_end\n\t"          // If start >= end, end loop
        "movb (%[str], %%ecx), %%al\n\t"    // al = str[ecx]
        "movb (%[str], %%esi), %%bl\n\t"    // bl = str[esi]
        "movb %%bl, (%[str], %%ecx)\n\t"    // str[ecx] = bl
        "movb %%al, (%[str], %%esi)\n\t"    // str[esi] = al
        "incl %%ecx\n\t"            // Increment start index
        "decl %%esi\n\t"            // Decrement end index
        "jmp reverse_loop\n\t"      // Repeat loop
        "loop_end:\n\t"
        :
        : [str] "r" (str), [len] "r" (length)
        : "%esi", "%ecx", "%al", "%bl"
    );

    // Print the reversed string
    printf("Reversed string: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}

What could be causing this error on my colleagues' machines? How can I fix it to work on all machines?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Are you trying to build 64bit code (rdx) or 32bit code (ecx)?

movb bl, (rbx, rcx) is a valid 64 bit instruction.  movb bl, (ebx, ecx) is a valid 32 bit instruction.  However, movb bl, (rbx, ecx) is invalid (for both).

Your code is 32 bit assembly code and your colleges compiled it for 64 bit.
Next time, use the preprocessor to validate the processor instruction set it the right one.
#ifndef __i386
#error This code requires 32 bit x86
#endif

